# Calculate works in numpy array but not in numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot, matrix, asarray


class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):
        random.seed(1)

        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1 # init weight from -1 to 1

    def __sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def __sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, train_input, train_output, iter):
        for i in range(iter):
            output = self.think(train_input)
            error = train_output - output

            adjustment = dot(train_input.T, error * self.__sigmoid_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights += adjustment

    def think(self, inputs):
        return self.__sigmoid(dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))




neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

train = matrix([[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0]])
train_input = asarray(train[:, 0:3])
train_output = asarray(train[:,3])

neural_network.train(train_input, train_output, 10000)
```

This code is a basic neural network. It works well when I convert the training set using `asarray`, but It does not work matrix itself. It seems matrix cannot calculate the sigmoid_derivative, and terminal shows `ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)`

Why matrix does not work in the code?

Comment: `np.matrix` is a subclass of `np.array` (ndarray) that looks somewhat like a MATLAB matrix.  It is always 2d, and uses `*` for the `dot` product.  If you don't really need to use it, stick with `array.  Is `x * (1 - x)` an element by element product, or matrix (dot) product.  Unless `x` is square it is going have dimension problems.

Comment: Because `matrix` is going to try to use matrix multiplication rather than elementwise multiplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the

```
 x * (1 - x)
```

expression.  `x` is (4,1) shape.  With the array element by element multiplication, this `x*(1-x)` works fine, returning another (4,1) result.

But if `x` is a (4,1) matrix, then `*` is the matrix product, the same `np.dot` for arrays.  That would require a (4,1) * (1,4) => (4,4), or a (1,4)*(4,1)=>(1,1).  You are already using `dot` for matrix product, so this derivative is clear the element wise one.

If you see machine learning code that uses `np.matrix` it is probably based on older examples, and retains `matrix` for backward compatibility.  It is better to use `array`, and use the `dot` product as needed.